High side switch with Raspberry Pi Pico
I'm looking for a circuit suggestion to drive a 5v resistive load that draws up to 400mA using a Raspberry Pi Pico with a high-side switching circuit. Most every example I could find used an external load voltage supply that was 9v or higher which makes it easier to use a PMOS FET. I considered using a relay but the ones I looked at require a significant amount of current (e.g. 100mA) which, when added to the load is too close to the USB limit of 500mA. I would prefer that the circuit have as little voltage drop as possible and that the circuit be non-inverting.


have you googled, "high side switch FET"?

Does "non-inverting" mean that the GPIO being HIGH turns the switch ON?

you can definitely find relays that take less than 100mA coil current. A quick search on FEC, I saw signal relays with coil resistance of 500R and 740R which is 10mA or less.

Are you sure you need a high-side switch? The complication here is that you want to control a 5V supply with 3.3V logic.
Single supply
If you wanted to run the load on 3.3V, it would be pretty straightforward:

There are hundreds of parts on Digikey that would work. The linked search is for PMOS FETs that are in SOT-23 surface-mount packages that can handle between 0.4A and 2A. The voltage across the transistor (Vds) would be 3.3V when the transistor is off, and much less when it's on. When searching datasheets, keep in mind that the listed Vds is a recommended maximum. The lowest specified transistor I found had a Vds of 12V, which means you could drive it with up to 12V before it hit a limit. Since the transistor can handle 12V, and you want to drive your load with either 3.3V or 5V, the part would work fine.
One thing to watch out for is Rdson (resistance across the transistor when it is on) which you want to be as low as reasonable. The higher the Rdson, the more voltage which will be dropped across it, leaving less for the load. Also, you will want a pullup so that the transistor is off when the Pico is not controlling it, and note that the transistor will be on when the GPIO is LOW, not HIGH.
You mentioned that you want this to be non-inverting, which I presume to mean that you want a HIGH GPIO output to turn the load on. That isn't really possible with PMOS, and you can't use an NMOS as a high-side switch. You would have to put in a NOT gate or something equivalent. This is something that is much easier to deal with in software.
Level Shifting
However, on your circuit, you want to power the load with 5V. Without some kind of active circuit, you would probably not be able to get a P-Channel MOSFET to work, since the gate voltage would never be zero -- it would be a minimum of -1.7V, which would probably still have a large leakage. Consider using another transistor as a level-shifter, like is frequently done in I2C. See NXP App Note 10441 for theory and details.

Low-side switch
If you used an NMOS as a low-side switch instead, you wouldn't have to worry about the power supply voltage being different from the control voltage. Also, this wouldn't be inverted the way the PMOS high-side switch is -- GPIO HIGH would turn it on, and LOW would turn it off. All you would need is a "logic-level" transistor, one which is sufficiently on with a gate voltage of 3.3V.
The voltage on the low terminal of the load would be a fraction of a volt above ground (depending on Rdson). For instance, if you had a transistor with an Rdson of 1R, it would form a voltage divider with the load of 12.5R. The transistor would get 5V(1R/13.5R)=370mV, so the load would get 4.63V across it. 1R is pretty high for this kind of transistor -- most of the ones on Digikey in the search above are
more like 0.1-0.5R.
You would have to decide if this is acceptable for your load, but it's usually OK for most loads except maybe for sensitive analog circuits like sensors.


A couple of SOT-23 parts can do this nicely.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The p-channel MOSFET is pretty low Rds(on) -typical 47mΩ- the plus side is that it will run cold at 400mA, but the minus side is that if your load has some capacitance to ground it could add a mighty negative-going transient to the 5V supply.
Through-hole low voltage parts are rare and are not likely to get any more common, so I suggest using modern SMT parts.

Here is a link to a similar thread:  High-side switch 24V 6mA control by Arduino
Here is that schematic.  Ignore the values for V1 and V2.

For your application, here is the parts list:
R1 - 750
R2 - 10 K
R3 - 100
Q1 - TIP30, TIP32
Q2 - 2N4401, 2N3904, 2N2222, etc.
Note:  The TIP power transistors are a bit overkill for this task.  A 2N4403 should work fine at 400 mA, but might get a bit warm.
